# SCH part of Jech's book

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I do not understand the purpose of the end of the last but one line and the last line in the following snippet from Jech's book:
if $2^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}\geq \kappa$ then $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}=2^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}.$ Namely, why the first condition with $\geq$ is assumed ?

[image]

Comment: You need some assumption to conclude $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf} \kappa}=2^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}$... it's not true in general. (I'm not sure what you're asking, exactly.)

Comment: The overall purpose of what Jech's expressing in this paragraph is to divide the computation of $\gimel(\kappa)$ up into two cases. The first case it is given by the continuum function on a regular cardinal and in the second case SCH gives you $\kappa^+.$ This solves the problem modulo continuum function on regular cardinals.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen SCH assumes that $<$ holds so I do not understand why do we care about the reverse there: $\geq$ ?? So, what is the purpose of the part after GCH word and first half of the last line ?

Comment: See my second comment. (Although I'm not sure there isn't more context here, I think this is what Jech is going for. I will look up the passage and make another comment if there is something more to add.) (Edit: looked it up.. looks like that is about it. Note before the next theorem he makes a comment about SCH determining cardinal arithmetic modulo continuum function on regular cardinals.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Is GCH used at all in the part from my comment above ?

Comment: Nope, it's always true that if $2^\lambda \ge \kappa$ then $\kappa^\lambda = 2^\lambda.$ Honestly this doesn't seem like very clear writing... the GCH part almost seems like a non-sequitur. What I think is going on in Jech's head is "The GCH solves cardinal arithmetic, and implies the SCH, which partially solves cardinal arithmetic."

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Please note that I'm a complete beginner to cardinal arithmetic. What item is called "the continuum function on regular cardinals" ?

Comment: The function $\kappa\mapsto 2^{\kappa},$ where the domain is the regular cardinals.

Answer (score 2):

I'll turn my comments into an answer to get this off the unanswered list...

The results of all cardinal exponentiation calculations are determined from the $\gimel$ function ($\kappa\mapsto \kappa^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}$) on singular cardinals, and the continuum function ($\kappa\mapsto 2^\kappa$) on regular cardinals. Jech demonstrates this in corollary 5.21, before the section on SCH. (Note that the gimel function and the continuum function give the same thing on regular cardinals, so we can really say that cardinal exponentiation is determined by the gimel function alone, which is how Jech puts it.)

What Jech is getting at in this confusingly terse passage is that SCH allows us to reduce the gimel function on singular cardinals to the continuum function on regular cardinals. He splits it up into two cases: The first case is: $2^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}\ge \kappa,$ then (in ZFC alone), we have $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}= 2^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa},$ which is the value of the continuum function on the regular cardinal $\operatorname{cf}\kappa.$ The second case is $2^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}< \kappa,$ in which the SCH says $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}$ takes its minimum possible value $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}=\kappa^+.$

So, since we can get gimel in terms of values of the continuum function on regular cardinals we should be able to reduce any computation $\kappa^\lambda$ to that as well. Jech puts this together in theorem 5.22, just after the passage you quoted.

Comment: One of the standard formulations of SCH is the statement that for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}=2^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}+\kappa^+$. Had Jech formulated it this way, the last two sentences of the quoted passage would make more sense. Maybe the text was written with this formulation in mind and not edited appropriately later one.